# Reusing a precompiled header in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have my own library project containing utilities which I reference in my other working projects. The library has its own precompiled header file:

```
// My_Library

// stdafx.h
#pragma once
#include "Lib_Class.h"

// stdafx.cpp (compile with /Yc"stdafx.h")
#include "stdafx.h"

// Lib_Class.h
class Lib_Class { ... }
```

In my working project I want a PCH which includes the library one plus some other files which I use all over the project but are specific to that project only.

```
// My_Project

// stdafx_proj.h
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h" // from My_Library
#include "Proj_Class.h"

// stdafx_proj.cpp (compile with /Yc"stdafx_proj.h")
#include "stdafx_proj.h"

// Proj_Class.h
#pragma once
class Proj_Class { ... }

// main.cpp (compile with /Yu"stdafx_proj.h")
#include "stdafx_proj.h"
...
Lib_Class lc;
Proj_Class pc;
...
```

So far so good. Now in `My_Project` I add a second class which references the previous ones:

```
// stdafx_proj.h
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Proj_Class.h"
#include "Proj_Class2.h"

// Proj_Class2.h
#pragma once
class Proj_Class2 {
    Lib_Class lc; // fine  
    Proj_Class pc; // syntax error - doesn't recognize Proj_Class
}
```

I can get around it by putting `#include "stadfx_proj.h"` at the top of `Proj_Class2.h` but is that a bad idea?

And why does `Proj_Class2` find `Lib_Class` but not `Proj_Class`?

Comment: This looks strange. Does the compile error happen when `stdafx_proj.cpp` is being compiled, or some other file?

Comment: Yes it happens when `stdafx_proj.cpp` is being compiled

Comment: Weird, I switched the order of `#include "Proj_Class.h"` and `#include "Proj_Class2.h"` in `stdafx_proj.h` and it started working!

Comment: Check your code for syntactic errors. E.g. I noticed you did not put `;` at the end of class declarations, which might lead to errors like this. If in doubt, what is included, generate pre-processed file (option /Fi of the cl.exe), and inspect it.